# No connection string found, but only at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, visual-studio-2012, objectdataprovider

Hi I'm fairly new to WPF and C#, so please be easy on me if this is just a silly question:

I'm using VS2012, Entity Framework to create a model of a pre-exisiting database and I would like to bind some tables to some ListView...
Now, I know there are different ways to do that but when I try to use an ObjectDataProvider I get an error at design time "No connection string named ... could be found in the application config file".

The strange thing is that if I run my application everything is working as it should, I just would like to remove that ugly error message and hopefully to get data in my list ad design time (that's why I would like to use an objectdataprovider).

Here are some parts of my code:

**App.Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BibliotecaEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=&quot;G:\PROGETTI-SOFTWARE\c# tests\Biblioteca\Biblioteca\biblioteca-db.mdf&quot;;initial catalog=BibliotecaDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**ListaScaffali.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Biblioteca.ShelvesList"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Biblioteca;assembly=" 
        Title="ShelvesList" Height="341" Width="609">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:BooksDB_Handler}" MethodName="TuttiGliScaffali" x:Key="ScaffaliObjSrc" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <ListView Name="listaScaffali" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ScaffaliObjSrc}}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scaffali Disponibili:" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Scaffale}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**BooksDB-Handler.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Biblioteca
{
    public static class BooksDB_Handler
    {

    ...

        public static ObservableCollection<Scaffali> TuttiGliScaffali()
        {
            using (var ctx = new BibliotecaEntities())
            {

                var reader = from d in ctx.Scaffali
                             select d;
                return new ObservableCollection<Scaffali>(reader);
            }
        }

    ...

    }
}
```

In my DB the Table "Scaffali" has only two columns: "ScaffaliID" (identity) and "Scaffale".

I read somewhere that this could be a Visual Studio bug and tried various things:

1. rebuild several times
2. avoid # in paths
3. compile for 32bits (I'm running Win8 x64)

but till now had no luck...

Thanks for your kind answer.

-= UPDATE 04/03/2013 =-

So far I still haven't found what are the conditions causing this strange behaviour, anyway I found that if I just build (not rebuild) two times in sequence the error message just disappear and everything seems to work as it should...

Comment: ...when I'm writing code and the application is not running. Maybe I used the wrong words to describe that phase?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and what I found out is that during design time, IDE does not seem to be reading the App.config to get the connection string so it blows up when establishing the connection. What I ended up doing is checking if code is in design time and manually creating a few of the items for design purposes.

I use the following code to find out if the environment is in design mode:

```
public static bool IsInDesignMode
{
    get
    {
        #if Silverlight
            return !HtmlPage.IsEnabled;;
        #else
            return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
        #endif
    }
}
```

Then in my code where I am returning the items I do the following:

```
if (IsInDesignMode)
{
    GetSampleData();
}
else
{
    GetQueryData();
}
```

And I simply implement those two methods.

There may be a better solution, but this worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that seems an effective solution but also make things a little bit more complex. I'm tring to use ObjectDataProviders to speed up the design of the UI: adding code complexit to achive that for me, at this time, doesn't really help. It seems to me that this is a VisualStudio Bug, what I would really like is to find out which conditions are making it expose and see if I can avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

This solution looked promising, but I have yet to get it to work for me...

Source: http://developernote.com/2012/03/rich-design-time-experience-with-wpf-and-ef-in-visual-studio-2010/

Sometimes the ability to see the data at design time significantly facilitates the creation of WPF controls. If I am developing a WPF control with complex UI using data bound controls, I usually define a property for accessing some typical data item:

```
public static ComplexData DesignTimeItem
{
    get
    {
        using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var products = from p in db.products.Include("ProductType")
                           where p.product_id == 131
                           select p;

            product product = products.First();

            return new ComplexData(product, "100 kg");
        }
    }
}
```

and then I use this property directly in XAML at design time:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeControl"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControlNamespace"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ComplexData.DesignTimeItem}, Mode=OneWay}"
    ...
>
```

Then I need to do the final step. The problem is that the default entity context constructor (DatabaseContext) uses the connection string included in run time application configuration file app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyModel.csdl|res://*/MyModel.ssdl|res://*/MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;password=******;User Id=myuser;server=myserver;database=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;charset=utf8&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

but at design time the application configuration file is **devenv.exe.config** which doesn’t include the connection string and so the creation of my WPF control fails causing the designer to fail to load. To solve this problem I simply copy the connection string included in **app.config** to **devenv.exe.config** located in **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\"** and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to construct the DataContext object with ConnectionString yourself instead of letting the framework use the one specified in configuration file? I usually prefer to construct that object myself, so i can easily move it to another assembly and inject the connection dependency. But that is another story. In your case, i would recommend you try these things:

1. Keep connection string in webconfig.
2. Construct the context yourself

   var connectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
                                                   {
                                                       Metadata = "{metadata}",
                                                       Provider = "{provider}",
                                                       ProviderConnectionString = "{connection string from config}"
                                                   };

   var ctx = new BibliotecaEntities(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

I just give a hint so you can try. I have not tried it with the full detail. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what I use to do in more familiar environments... I'll try your suggestion, thanks.